# change a div with ajax when change a select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have some problem to update a div when I change a select.

First I create my select in a view like this.

```
=collection_select(:department, :id, Department.all, :id, :name, options={:prompt=>"Seleccione departamento"})
```

now I create a ajax call to take the value of the select and find all the date to match

```
:javascript
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#department_id').change(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url:"/movements/find_by_department",
      type: "GET",
      data: {valor: $('#department_id').val()}
    });
  });
  })
```

the next step was create a method  "find_by_department" to take the value .. and show something

```
 def find_by_department
    id_department = (params[:valor])
    @ideas_department = Idea.find_by_department_id(id_department)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js {render :department_chart}
    end
  end
```

Now is my problem, I have a partial "department_chart" with this

```
$("#my_id4").html("@ideas_department")
```

but the id="my_id4" don't change

by the other hands, I see this in console

```
Started GET "/movements/find_by_department?valor=5" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-22 09:50:04 +0100
Processing by MovementsController#show as */*
  Parameters: {"valor"=>"5", "id"=>"find_by_department"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 10 LIMIT 1
  Option Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "options".* FROM "options" WHERE "options"."name" = 'ideas_status_updated_date' LIMIT 1
```

I don´t no why call the show method

I have this in my router

```
  get 'movements/find_by_department', :as => 'find_by_department'
```

Comment: Show your config/routes.rb

Comment: Do you want to change my_id4 to my_id5, if 5 is coming in your request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change you routes like this:

```
resources :movements do
   get 'find_by_department', on: :member      
end
```

change your javascript code to this:

```
 :javascript
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#department_id').change(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url:"/movements/#{$('#department_id').val()}/find_by_department",
      type: "GET"
    });
  });
  })
```

In your controller :

```
def find_by_department
 @ideas_department = Idea.find_by_department_id(params[:id])

 respond_to do |format|
  format.js {render :department_chart}
 end
```

end

If you want to change your id on the basis of id coming from request, than change your code to this:

```
$("#my_id#{@ideas_department.id }").html("<%= @ideas_department %>")
```

Hope it will help. Thanks